# .NET: Custom format for web service documentation?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, documentation

For a web service created in .NET, navigating to the service in a browser results in a somewhat brief listing of methods in the service and any description that is provided.

**Is there any way to customize the format of the documentation for .NET web services?**

*Customization might include something as simple as customizing the styles on the page or as complex as completely overriding the generated HTML.  Any point in the right direction is appreciated.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040609.htm), looks like it covers the bases but I haven't ever tried this.

The basic idea is to modifiy your web.config `wsdlHelpGenerator` element like the below snippet

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <webServices>
         <wsdlHelpGenerator href="Path/To/Custom/HelpGenerator.aspx"/>
      </webServices>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I was writing a REST endpoint and wanted to produce some rudimentary documentation, I used [this blog entry](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/29/rest-services-and-metadata-endpoints-in-wcf/) as a starting point. It worked well.